# Write a script file (.bat or .cmd) for Windows, so I can autorun an existing Django Project on any Windows 10 PC with Python preinstalled

Tags: python, django, powershell, command-prompt, autorun

I already finished a Django project (development mode) and I just want to run it from any Windows PC with Python pre-installed.
My project folder **already includes a venv folder** that was created when I create a virtual enviroment in PyCharm.

I create a simple .cmd file and include this commands.

```
venv\Scripts\activate
python manage.py runserver
```

I put this file inside the project file on the **same level with manage.py file and venv folder**.

I don't know why but problem is that command prompt open and close without any error. I tried to run as administrator but nothing changes.

When I manually open the command prompt, change the directory to the project file and run the above commands (enable virtual enviroment and runserver) everything works perfectly fine.

In addition when I add this line on the top

```
cd D:\PycharmProjects\MyProject
```

which is the directory of my Project, nothing happens.

I don't want any solution that includes installing anything more than Python (Git for Windows or such), I prefer to write a script file to successfully run `python manage.py runserver` with success with something that is already preistalled by default with Windows (Command Prompt or PowerShell)

Thanks.

Comment: are you planning on running in for development or production?

Comment: Running in for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the below a try .. it worked for me on Windows 10.
**Remember you must be in the .bat file's folder for this to work.**
The extra line will fire up your default browser.

```
@echo off
title Start Batch
color 0a
start cmd.exe /C "venv\Scripts\activate && cd app && python m_dev.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
start http://127.0.0.1:8001
```